# How to upload a hex file to dsPIC33 from linux command line?

Tags: shell, microcontroller, microchip, mplab, dspic

I want to write a script to upload the hex file from host computer to dsPIC33 and hence need a command line utility or API to do the same.

Till now I have been programming the chip with the MPLAB IPE with ICD4.

I tried to search for the same and found that people have done it with `ipecmd` utility, but could not find a package for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

The ipecmd.jar is the command line utility that can be used to flash the devices from command line.

The documentation can be found in the MPLab installation directory. Something like

> mplabx/v5.05/docs/Readme%20for%20IPECMD.htm

Answer (score 2):

`ipecmd.sh` is part of the MPLab-X IPE, typically found at `/opt/microchip/mplabx/v*/mplab_ipe/` (where `*` is the version number). It's really just a wrapper around `ipecmd.jar`, though. The latest version is found [here](https://www.microchip.com/mplab/mplab-x-ide).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, `ipecmd.sh` did the trick. Found that under `/opt/microchip/mplabx/v5.05/mplab_platform/mplab_ipe` on my distribution. Thanks a lot @Benny Mac